# Sharepoint Designer cons in 2010, are they still relevant in 2013?

Tags: 2010, 2013, sharepoint-designer

I came across this [article](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/8778.sharepoint-2010-best-practices-is-sharepoint-designer-really-pure-evil.aspx) on TechNet for the 2010 version of Sharepoint Designer, in particular the author mentions 3 cons about it (below).  I'm keen to understand if these cons are still relevant in the 2013 version of SharePoint Designer? The cons are:

- A lot of changes made using SharePoint Designer can't be backed up or
  moved.
- SharePoint Designer makes it too easy for users to edit
  everything
- SharePoint Designer will store content in the
  filesystem, making it unghosted and unavailable for backup and not
  really optimal in a load balanced Web server farm.

Comment: Yes all the 3 cons are still relevant in 2013. Major change with Designer 2013 is that now we don't have design view available. Below is the link which can give you more detail view on 2013 designer <http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj728659(v=office.15).aspx>

Comment: Thanks Amit, for those 3 cons do you have any real work examples related to them or ways around the issues??